# laravel get eloquent return null for specific column if another column is not specific word

Tags: laravel

I have query something like this:

```
 Order::where('order_id', 2)
   ->leftJoin('test', 'test.order_id', '=', 'orders.order_id')
   ->get(['order.status, 'order.path', 'test.name']);
```

Now, what I want to achieve is the following. in `get` clause, when fetching specific columns, if `'order.status'` isn't `COMPLETED`, return `'order.path' as null`, if `'order.status'` is `COMPLETED`, then return actual `order.path`

Answer (score 0):

You should try to loop the result, then apply the change what you want.

```
$orders = Order::where('order_id', 2)
->leftJoin('test', 'test.order_id', '=', 'orders.order_id')
->get(['order.status, 'order.path', 'test.name']);

for($i = 0; i < orders.lenght();i++){
  if(orders[i].status != 'COMPLETED'){
    orders[i].path = null;
  }
}
```